# how to send send the data using python django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to send the json data using post request in django python.
I have a code for get the data and I don't use any html file.

```
class employeeList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        employee1 = employees.objects.all()
        serializer = employeeSerializer(employee1, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self,request):
        pass
```

can you please help for post request.Now I want to create post function to send the data

Comment: Please see the documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#pulling-it-all-together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this basically,

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = employeeSerializer(data=request.data)  
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response({'message':'Data davet succesfully'})
```

Comment: I have another dought can you explain it

Comment: Sure, what is the problem?

Comment: I want update the data using Id value.I will try but I didn't get it

Comment: can you please give the solution

Comment: You can use  put() method like post method.But your serializer must contains pk field.Or you can use UpdateAPIView. it is very usefull. You can find other drf generic views [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply dump query set into Json format like:

```
def post(self, request):
    data = list(employees.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)  
               # or 
    return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```